# How to get result if exactly one match inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write a query to join two tables and return result if exactly one match in there. I have to discard results if zero match and more than one match.

All I am looking for is to extend the INNER JOIN. Let me just get to the point. I have two tables Dept & Emp. One Dept can have multiple Emp's & not the other way around.

```
     Table Dept
```

[image]

```
      Table Emp
```

[image]

I need to JOIN it on Dept_id

```
   Expected Results
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery for  group by dept_id haing count = 1

```
 select  t.dept_id, dept.dept_name, emp.Emp_name
 from (
  select dept_id
  from emp 
  group by  dept_id 
  having count(*) = 1
 ) t 
 INNER JOIN dept on t.dept_id = dept.dept_id 
 INNER JOIN emp ON t.dept_id = emp.dept_id
```

Comment: Column 'Emp.Emp_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can join with a not exists condition:

```
select d.*, e.emp_id, e.emp_name
from dept d
inner join emp e
    on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from emp e1 
        where e1.dept_id = d.dept_id and e1.emp_id != e.emp_id
    )
```

Comment: I would put the `not exists` in a `where` clause (subqueries in the `on` clause scare a lot of people), but I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to existing solutions can be one using analytics (window functions), 
instead of joining twice:

```
select dept_id, dept_name, emp_id, emp_name
from
(    
  SELECT 
    d.Dept_id, d.Dept_name, e.Emp_id, e.Emp_Name, 
    count(*) over (partition by d.dept_id) cnt1
  FROM d 
  INNER JOIN e
  ON d.Dept_id = e.Dept_id
) where cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, try below query;

```
SELECT a.depid dept_id,dept_name,emp_id,emp_name
FROM
(SELECT case WHEN count(*)=1 THEN dept_id END depid FROM emp GROUP BY dept_id) a INNER JOIN emp ON depid=dept_id
INNER JOIN dept b ON a.depid = b.dept_id 
WHERE depid IS NOT NULL
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase this as an aggregation query in Oracle:

```
select d.dept_id, d.dept_name,
       max(e.emp_id) as emp_id, 
       max(e.emp_name) as emp_name
from dept d inner join
     emp e
     using (dept_id)
group by d.dept_id, d.dept_name
having count(*) = 1;
```

This works because if there is only one match, then `max()` returns the value from the one row.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be

```
select d.dept_id, d.dept_name, e.emp_name
from   emp e
       join dept d on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
where  e.dept_id in
       ( select dept_id from emp group by dept_id having count(*) = 1 )
```